# CakePHP 3 dynamic form fields

Tags: php, cakephp, save, cakephp-3.0

I try to implement this tutorial https://waltherlalk.com/blog/dynamic-form-input-fields **to the CakePHP 3**, everything works fine until I submit the form. It doesn't save any grades. I've read many threads here but nothing helped yet.

I guess there is a controller issue, so here's my controller:

```
    public function add()
{
    $student = $this->Students->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $student = $this->Students->patchEntity($student, $this->request->getData()); 
        if ($this->Students->save($student, ['associated' => ['Grades']])) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The student has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The student could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $this->set(compact('student'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['student']);
}
```

Grades.ctp:

```
 <?php
    $key = isset($key) ? $key : '{{ key }}';
    // I changed <%= key %> to {{ key }}
?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $this->Form->hidden("grade.{$key}.id") ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->text("grade.{$key}.subject",array("id"=>"grade{$key}Subject")); ?>
    </td>   
    <td>
        <?php echo $this->Form->select("grade.{$key}.grade", array(
            'A+',
            'A',
            'B+',
            'B',
            'C+',
            'C',
            'D',
            'E',
            'F'
        ), array(
            'empty' => '-- Select grade --',
            "id"=>"grade{$key}grade"
        )); ?>
    </td>
    <td class="actions">
        <a href="#" class="remove">Remove grade</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And add.ctp:

```
<?php
/**
  * @var \App\View\AppView $this
  */
?>
<nav class="large-3 medium-4 columns" id="actions-sidebar">
    <ul class="side-nav">
        <li class="heading"><?= __('Actions') ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Students'), ['action' => 'index']) ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Grades'), ['controller' => 'Grades', 'action' => 'index']) ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('New Grade'), ['controller' => 'Grades', 'action' => 'add']) ?></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="students form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($student) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Student') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->control('name');
        ?>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Grades');?></legend>
    <table id="grade-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Grade achieved</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td class="actions">
                    <a href="#" class="add">Add grade</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</fieldset>

<script id="grade-template" type="text/x-underscore-template">
    <?php echo $this->element('grades');?>
</script>

    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //I changed undescore default template settings
        _.templateSettings = {
          interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
        }

        var
            gradeTable = $('#grade-table'),
            gradeBody = gradeTable.find('tbody'),
            gradeTemplate = _.template($('#grade-template').remove().text()),
            numberRows = gradeTable.find('tbody > tr').length;

        gradeTable
            .on('click', 'a.add', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $(gradeTemplate({key: numberRows++}))
                    .hide()
                    .appendTo(gradeBody)
                    .fadeIn('fast');
            })
            .on('click', 'a.remove', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                $(this)
                    .closest('tr')
                    .fadeOut('fast', function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
            });

            if (numberRows === 0) {
                gradeTable.find('a.add').click();
            }
    });
</script>
```

Debug:

```
/src/Controller/StudentsController.php (line 55)
[
    'name' => 'asdad',
    'grade' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'id' => '',
            'subject' => 'adsads',
            'grade' => '0'
        ]
    ]
]
/src/Controller/StudentsController.php (line 56)
object(App\Model\Entity\Student) {

    'name' => 'asdad',
    'grade' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'id' => '',
            'subject' => 'adsads',
            'grade' => '0'
        ]
    ],
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'name' => true,
        'grade' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Students'

}
```

If you know about any other tutorial how to implement dynamic form into add page let me please know. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any error ? Have you checked the ajax request if the data are sent correctly?

Comment: I added debug, check it please.

Comment: Sorry I am from phone and cannot reproduce your program. Wild guess check your spelling somehow probably trying to save wrong grades.
As long as you send correct data and saving the entity Students without problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your grades data isn't being converted to entities as can be seen in your debug output, it's just an array, which indicates that you are targeting the wrong property.

By convention the entities association property for a `hasMany` association is the underscored plural variant of the association alias, so in case of an association named `Grades`, that would be `grades`, not `grade`.

So make sure to rename all this `grade.{$key}` and `grade{key}` stuff to `grades.{$key}` and `grades{$key}` accordingly.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Saving Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-associations)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Saving HasMany Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-hasmany-associations)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Creating Inputs for Associated Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#associated-form-inputs)**

Comment: I have a very similar issue but I have the records saving, the problem is new records are being created instead of the existing ones already being saved. Have you had a similar issue?

Comment: @mederomuraliev You're probably not passing the primary key(s) of the existing records.

Comment: nevermind, it was a conflicting event that inserted new records on the parent record which I totally wasn't accounting for :)